# NextJs: Is it possible to load a static page (with dynamic routes) inside of a modal?

Tags: next.js

Goal: Open statically generated pages inside of a modal on the home page.

I have a number of statically generated articles using getStaticProps/getStaticPaths. I also have a homepage which displays a collection of links to these articles. When one link is clicked, I would like to open that page in a modal rather than completely redirect to the article.

I have figured out how to do this somewhat by using the href/as properties in the  tag. From there, I can use the router to grab the slug and fetch the article client-side. However, since they are static pages, I'd much rather be able to access the static props to load the page.

Is there a way to access the static pages that next builds and load them into a modal component?

I have tried implementations in both Next12 and Next13, and am willing to use whichever version I find a solution for.

Comment: did you figure out a solution? I ran into exactly the same problem today...